# How can I use Linux bash with powershell keybindings style for text selection

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, shell, ubuntu

I am new to Linux ( Ubuntu ), I used to work with Windows so it works with the `PowerShell` terminal interface for running commands.

As soon as I open Linux `bash`, I find myself natively hitting `Powershell`'s keybindings such:

- Selecting one letter at once: `shift+left`
- Selecting one word at once: `ctrl+shift+left`
- removing text that I selected: `ctrl+shift+left` (for selecting), then `backspace`
- copying or cutting selected text: `ctrl+shift+left` (for selecting), then `ctrl+c` or `ctrl+x`

I am used to this, as I believe it makes me more productive when dealing with CLIs, but `bash` has its own binding which I already learned and knew, but no matter I find myself using `Powershell`'s.

is there any way that I can achieve similar key bindings of `PowerShell` that I mentioned while using `bash`?

Please, I wanna hear anything from you.

Comment: AFIK, bash uses the _readline_ library, and this means that you can do some configuration in [`~/.inputrc`](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-inputrc.html). However, this question is not really about programming, and I suggest that you ask it at [unix.stackexchange.com](unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is useful, thank you! yeah I realized that, I will move it.